# Random black screen (no freeze)

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I use two monitors, 1 HDMI and 1 VGA.
My computer randomly goes into a black screen on both monitors and I waited for it to happen again and checked the event log and this is what I found:

[image]

**translated:**

```
Proces C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\AI Suite II\AI Suite II.exe (proces-id:3544) reverting policyscheme from {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e} to {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e}
```

It's something with the AI Suite of ASUS.
But I can't find anything else about this on the web.

**PC Specs - NVIDIA Control Panel -> System Information**

```
Motherboard:        ASUS Rampage IV Formula
Operating System:   Windows 8.1 Pro, 64-bit
DirectX version:    11.0 
GPU processor:      GeForce GTX 760
Driver version:     332.21
Direct3D API version:   11.1
Direct3D feature level: 11_0
CUDA Cores:     1152 
Core clock:     1019 MHz 
Memory data rate:   6008 MHz
Memory interface:   256-bit 
Memory bandwidth:   192.26 GB/s
Total available graphics memory:    4096 MB
Dedicated video memory: 2048 MB GDDR5
System video memory:    0 MB
Shared system memory:   2048 MB
```

Comment: Do you have two separate monitors or one single monitor with VGA and HDMI plugged in with your respected two GPU cards (integrated + Nvidia)?

Comment: @Hunter I have only got one GPU, my TV is connected to the HDMI port and my VGA monitor connected to the DVI with DisplayPort (VGA) adapter.

Comment: Check whether the two wires are connected to two different graphics card. Two GPUs are the Nvidia Geforce and integrated graphics cards. Please check that both have one wire connected. Also check if your bios accepts both of these cards at the same time. I would also recommend to uninstall the Asus AI Suite if it's not of much use.